# Xorg failed to find /root/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log Advice

Tags: debian, x11, root, startx

I am currently working on a display manager for linux using the `startx` command.

The program is running as *root* (as a display manager normally does) and then drops to a normal user (in this case *kuglatec*).

I tested and verified it using `whoami` which returned kuglatec.

Then I started the x server but it cant locate the log file at `/root/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log` which it shouldn't actually do since xorg isn't running as root and the log file is located an `/home/kuglatec/.local/share/xorg/Xorg.0.log`.

I think that xorg somehow runs as root and tries to access the nonexistent file. Any ideas?

Source code of the operating function: https://pastebin.com/GqT28xyq

Comment: Why are you using `startx`.  Debian uses SystemD, and the service is already running if you installed any type of Desktop environment.  `Startx` will never start due to a collision with the running service.  The service in use depends on the Desktop environment chosen.

Comment: The Xorg command has an option to specify the location of the logfile: Xorg -logfile <filename>, so I was wondering if that was of any use in this situation.

Comment: @eyoung100 there’s no conflict here, it’s entirely possible to run multiple X servers and multiple display managers (each on its own VT). The OP could also have disabled or uninstalled the default display manager.

Comment: Yes, i did disable the default manager (gdm) using 'sudo systemctl disable gdm'

Comment: "I think that xorg somehow runs as root"… Well… only somehow then. As far as I recall, if running as root, the log would sit in /var/log.  Moreover, (if I recall correctly) If the log file (whatever) does not exist xorg will create it silently… unless of course not being permitted to do so… as would probably kuglatec be in the root-user directory.

Comment: This could be an environment variable issue, with $HOME still set as `/root` after dropping the user; that is the difference between `sudo -i` and `sudo -s` for example; try inspecting that variable in your program before you start Xorg as the unprivileged user.

Comment: @PhilippLudwig : I do share your explanation since it would be a valid reason for what I had written above.  If only Kuglatec could confirm.

Comment: Going to try that by setting the var

Comment: [X applications](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Running_GUI_applications_as_root) should not be run as root.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
setting the environtment variable for $HOME resolved the issue and X is just working fine!